# Does a non-magical +1 weapon get a +1 bonus added to the attack roll only, or the damage roll as well?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

This question pertains to D&D 5e. I visited a bladesmith in a solo adventure as an EVENT. He improved my Battleaxe to a +1 non-magical weapon.

Is this +1 bonus added to the attack roll only, or the damage roll as well?

Comment: Was this a solo adventure as in there was no DM? Was this a published adventure? If so, what's the name of the adventure? (The site can only guess what a particular DM intended, for instance, but may be able to help if the event appears in a published adventure.)

Answer (score 11):

### Existing items do not offer mundane with +X

There are currently no official items that grant a +1 to either attack or damage that aren't also magical.

That leaves us without guidance from existing material and whatever your source material you have is going to contain your answer. If this is homebrew (or if there is no stat block), then it is up to the DM to determine the statistics of the weapon.

### It will depend on the weapon's defined stat block

Whether it's +1 to Attack, Damage, or Attack + Damage will be determined by the stat block of the weapon.

If you are using a published adventure or module, you'll need to check the stat block for the weapon.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that there is no nonmagical +1 weapon in any official publication.

Comment: “[N]o magic items […] that aren’t also magical,” is a little bit like, “well... yes? Were you expecting otherwise?” Perhaps better to say that non-magical weapons don’t usually (ever, so far as I know?) give +1 bonuses to _anything_. In fact, it might be best to start with that. I don’t think closing is (remotely) productive here—this looks pretty plainly like something a DM invented that a new player didn’t realize was unofficial, so explaining the confusion is vastly better than closing.

Comment: @KRyan OP has said this was a solo adventure...but I honestly am not sure if that's solo as in one player or solo as a in DM and one player. But yeah, let me see if I can restructure this. I agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

### There are no official rules for this situation so you will need to work this out with your DM

Fifth edition Dungeons & Dragons largely avoids numerical bonuses (aside from the traditional +x magic weapons and armour) in favour of the advantage mechanic, and also reduces the importance of mundane gear to highlight class abilities and ensure magic items feel special. Thus there are very few rules which provide flat bonuses to rolls, and only magic weapons provide a “+1” bonus (or better), to both attack rolls and damage. That puts this situation in the territory of a house rule, so you will need to discuss it with your Dungeon Master to determine their intent.

### They may be using a rule from a previous edition, or making a house rule based on the same

One model for how it might work is the concept of “Masterwork Weapons” from the game’s third edition. These were mundane weapons of the highest quality, which granted a +1 bonus to attack rolls, but not to damage. This made them useful but not overwhelming, while also far cheaper than magic weapons (and it was in fact a requirement that magic weapons be created from masterwork ones).

Whether your DM is using this rule at all, or making something else up themselves, only they can answer, but it is worth noting that even a small bonus has a great deal more impact in fifth edition than previous ones. This is due to the concept of “bounded accuracy” - that all combatants only have attack bonuses and armour class within a fairly small range, compared to the third and fourth editions, where the bonuses could (and did) grow much larger.